# Pre-populate image to FilePond input with `storeAsFile: true` option

Tags: filepond

I want to initiate FilePond with pre-populated images like this:

```
FilePond.create(inputElement, {
    "storeAsFile": true,
    "files": [
        {
            "source": "http://localhost/products/storage/main/dark.jpg",
            "options": {"type":"local"}
        }
     ]
});
```

But I got this error: `Error during load. 400 (can't load URL)`

I want to use FilePond in `replace input file` mode.

I can fix error by setting server load URL and it will load images properly but then when I want to upload new files it try to send files to server URL and don't consider `"storeAsFile": true` option.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I should use something like this:

```
FilePond.create(inputElement, {
    "storeAsFile": true,
    "server": {
        "load": "http://localhost/products/storage/",
    },
    "files": [
        {
            "source": "main/dark.jpg",
            "options": {"type":"local"}
        }
     ]
});
```

and I shouldn't set any thing like `server: {'url': 'anything', 'load': 'other url'}` option.